# "Гореть своим делом" и "человек собрал вокруг себя людей" - из контекста всё ясно, а как быть с формальной стороной проблемы?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> — Играли ли вы на американской сцене?
>
> — Нет, но работала в русском театре «Подиум». Нам помогал один
>   замечательный человек, который, продав свою недвижимость в России,
>   уехал в Америку и ставил на вырученные средства спектакли. Я не знаю,
>   вернулись ли ему деньги (разговор не об этом), но он действительно
>   **из тех, кто горит своим делом**. Этот **человек собрал вокруг себя людей**, любящих театр, и, хотя у каждого из них была своя жизнь, они
>   приходили вечерами после работы и играли с такой искренностью и
>   желанием, каких не увидишь в Москве.

Comment: Как-то коряво звучит "вернулись ли ему деньги".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы приняла всё как есть. Гореть - отдаваться полностью какому-нибудь делу. Конечно, привычнее "гореть на работе", но ведь есть *гореть* - испытывать сильное чувство, можно сказать "горел желанием работать", "горел любовью к работе, к делу", а так как в разговорной речи тенденция к сокращениям, по-моему, возможно гореть и своим делом - как образное выражение.

*Человек собрал вокруг себя людей, любящих театр...* - воспринимается не как излишество, там же объясняется, каких именно людей.